# /login.xhtml Not Found in ExternalContext as a Resource

Tags: jsf

Hi guys I created a simple web app using primefaces. When I deploy the app on a JBoss AS7 and try to open a webpage I get the follwoing error:

Just to let you know that I place all the .xhtml files under the webapp.

My Stacktrace

```
20:06:22,318 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].          [/EjbProjectManagementApplication].[Faces Servlet]] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1) Servlet.service() for   servlet Faces Servlet threw exception: com.sun.faces.context.FacesFileNotFoundException: /login.xhtml      Not Found in ExternalContext as a Resource
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.resolveURL(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:232) [jsf-  impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.resolveURL(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:273) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.getMetadataFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:209) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.application.view.ViewMetadataImpl.createMetadataView(ViewMetadataImpl.java:114) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:233) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:116) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_32]
```

My faces-config.xml is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<faces-config
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">
    <managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>loginBean</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>org.managedBeans.LoginBean</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
    </managed-bean>

    <managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>ProjectEntityHandlerBean</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>org.managedBeans.ProjectEntityHandlerBean</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
    </managed-bean>
    <managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>departmentEntityHandlerBean</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>org.managedBeans.DepartmentEntityHandlerBean</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
    </managed-bean>
    <managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>employeeEntityHandlerBean</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>org.managedBeans.EmployeeEntityHandlerBean</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
    </managed-bean>
    <managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>partnerEntityHandlerBean</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>org.managedBeans.PartnerEntityHandlerBean</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
    </managed-bean>
    <navigation-rule>
        <display-name>login.xhtml</display-name>
        <from-view-id>/login.xhtml</from-view-id>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>failure</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/failure.xhtml</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
    </navigation-rule>
    <navigation-rule>
        <display-name>success.xhtml</display-name>
        <from-view-id>/success.xhtml</from-view-id>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>project</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/project.xhtml</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
    </navigation-rule>
    <navigation-rule>
        <display-name>login.xhtml</display-name>
        <from-view-id>/login.xhtml</from-view-id>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>success</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/project.xhtml</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
    </navigation-rule>


</faces-config>
```

My web.xml is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app version="3.0"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         metadata-complete="false"           >
 <display-name>svntoyapplication</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>login.xhtml</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
          <servlet>
                  <servlet-name>health</servlet-name>
                  <jsp-file>/health.jsp</jsp-file>
         </servlet>
         <servlet-mapping>
                  <servlet-name>health</servlet-name>
                  <url-pattern>/health</url-pattern>
         </servlet-mapping>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>  
  </servlet-mapping> 
    <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <context-param>
    <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>client</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
    <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.allowTextChildren</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
  </listener>  
</web-app>
```

Could someone please help me identifying the error??

Comment: Did you really create it yourself? That's not exactly "simple" and a rather JSF 1.x flavored configuration. Is this a copypasted/cloned project or something? Why don't you just start off clean from nothing? Are you absolutely positive that you're concentrating on JSF 2.x targeted resources/books/tutorials and not on outdated JSF 1.x ones?

Comment: While I'm somewhat weirded out by the fact you're seeing this instead of a `404` error, the only possible explanation for this is JSF can't find the viewId you specified. Show your directory structure here and also the exact URL you're trying to access. Also, why do you have two different URL mappings for your JSF files? Are you actually planning to use both URL styles in your application?

Comment: Well BalcusC you are right , I copy/pase the faces-config and modified it.I m using JSF 2.0.
Kolossus , no I m not planning to use both mappings. I m using only the second one. Again it was copy/paste from another project while trying to get my project working. I will remove the first one
My problem was solved. It was stupid me that placed the .xhtml files in the wrong directory. Thank you guys for your tips.

Comment: @panipsilos I was stupid too. Thank you to open my eyes!