# Why doesn't FacesServlet find .xhtml Facelet?

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, servlets, myfaces

I've created an JSF Project from my Eclipse with JBoss Tools. Now I have the structure:

```
MyProjectFolder
 ⌊ WebContent
   ⌊ WEB-INF
   |  ⌊ lib
   |  ⌊ faces-config.xml
   |  ⌊ web.xml
   ⌊ META-INF
   ⌊ index.xhtml
```

My web.xml maps the following extensions to the FacesServlet: `/faces/*`, `*.jsf`, `*.faces`

When I now try to access `/faces/index.xhtml`, `index.jsf` and `index.faces` I get a 404 not found error. Only when I access index.xhtml directly I get a page but without jsf-content (what is clear for me).

So my question is now how the FacesServlet resolves the Faclet-Filename and path from my URL-Params? And how can I ensure, that it is not possible to access the index.xhtml directly?

PS I know the solution to add a servlet-mapping for *.xhtml but I think there should be an alternative.

Regards!

Comment: <webapp>/faces/index.xhtml should actually work. What did you use as "welcome-file" in web.xml ?

Comment: No welcome file defined.

Comment: Sorry, but I get for /faces/index.xhtml the 404 again.

Comment: *"I know the solution to add a servlet-mapping for *.xhtml"*. Please confirm if it also *really* have solved the concrete problem. I don't think so, but you're implying otherwise which is pretty strange. If it did, then please post more detail about your minimum necessary project configuration in order to reproduce the problem. Tell which MyFaces version exactly you're using, tell how you configured the JARs, show the entire web.xml, etc.

Comment: Why do you have multiple URL patterns for your FacesServlet? Do you actually plan to use all those patterns? See http://stackoverflow.com/q/13145248/1530938